# Do Nexus users need write access to repos in a group or just write access to the group?

Tags: maven, nexus, roles

I gave devs a URL to a maven group repo that has some repos in it. The devs have read/write access to the repos within the group, and read access to the group, but not write access to the group. Do they need write access to the group in order to be able to publish to the group URL or will it be ok since they already have write access to the repos in the group?

Comment: The different repos having write access to is enough...usually only two repos are necessary which means a SNAPSHOT repo and a release repo nothing more is really needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot publish to a group URL, they are meant to be read only groups for underlying repos. Read only access should be fine as a result. Generally you'd publish to a hosted repo (and a specific one at that), so you'd want read/write access to that repo, and to give the developers the appropriate URL.